# Is "a bottle of wine" outdated to refer to alcoholic drink?

Tags: word-usage

I asked a friend in UK and got a confirmation the following sentence is an everyday language in UK.

> "buy a bottle of wine"

However, searching for the keywords "a bottle of wine" on Amazon gives me this:

[image]

just empty wine bottles.

"buy a bottle of wine" seems better, search results includes some wine bottle openers and bottles of wine:

[image]

Simply "wine" gives the most weird, which is Women's Slippers!

[image]

Is "a bottle of wine" too old-time to get what I want? If yes, what keywords should I use?

Comment: You never know what Amazon does with your input! Do you enter the phrase including the quotes? What could you do on Amazon other than buying? Why not simply enter `wine` in the search field?

Comment: Amazon's search function can be fairly inexplicable at the best of times, not helped by typographical and grammatical 'issues' with some of the listings, not to mention 'keyword stuffing'.  Your phrase would be fine in any other context.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler simply "wine" gives the most weird, which is Women's Slippers!

Comment: Amazon probably just tokenizes your input to individual search terms. Try "bottled wine" or just "red wine" and/or "white sine". And don't interpret search results as English usage guidelines.

Comment: This is not really a question about English, but about how to use a website. Amazon isn't a place I think of to buy wine, and I don't think they sell much directly in the U.S. due to our patchwork of alcohol control laws; they'll route you to Amazon Fresh, Whole Foods, or third party vendors who use their platform. If you don't narrow down the department to "Grocery" or the equivalent in your locale, they'll show you what "wine" item sells and gives them the most profit overall—which probably isn't wine itself, but wine-themed gifts, wine glassware and accessories, and wine-colored clothing.

Comment: If I'm signed in, the top results are various bottled and boxed wines—from Whole Foods (344 results). I don't know if it is legal to advertise alcohol as "promoted items"; I don't see any. If I browse in incognito mode, the top results are wine glasses and wine guide books, and the top category is indeed "women's novelty socks & hosiery" (i.e. socks with wine sayings on them). If I scroll down far enough I do see a bottle of cabernet for sale, though being signed out it "cannot be shipped to your selected location." But it's Robert Mondavi, so maybe it doesn't count as wine either :-).

Answer (score 2):

It is as fine as it has ever been, as [this Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bottle+of+wine&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows:

[image]

As your friend and the commenters here say, if I may summarize it, humans are better at interpreting language than computers.